# Using GoogleAPIClient/Gmail with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, gmail-api

My aim is to try and fetch emails for a Gmail account. I tried to look at some documentation around using Gmail APIs in Swift. Was successfully able to do the [log in steps](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating) and request for the desired scopes.

Post this I dont seem to be able to find any documentation or help about fetching emails on iOS. Every suggestion on Stackoverflow is 5-6 years old and seems outdated. I came across the pod **GoogleAPIClient/Gmail** but when using GTLQuery it keeps throwing the error that

 *Type 'GTLQuery' has no member 'queryForUsersMessagesGet'*

Could someone please guide me?

Comment: You should include a sample of the code that's giving you an error.

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example].  Signin is not oauth